# How to make a user see the records of his/her business unit as well as the parent business unit in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am new in Microsoft Dynamics CRM and I want to achieve the following goal: 
I Have Three Business Units lets say "Parent Business Unit", "Child Business Unit 1" and "Child Business unit 2". "Child Business Unit 1" and "Child Business unit 2" are the Child Business unit of "Parent Business Unit". Also I have two users lets say "Joe" and "Beck". Now I want to do something like this: Joe and Beck can access the records of "Parent Business Unit" as well as "Child Business unit 1" but not the records of "Child Business unit 2".

I've Tried making the Team and Security Roles but that didn't solved my problem, also in this situation I can't figure out that whether to put "Joe" and "Beck" in "Parent Business Unit" or in "Child Business Unit 1".

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a Parent BU Team.
2. Assign at least one security role to this team giving access to data only accessible with BU-level privileges.
3. Make Joe and Beck members of the Parent BU Team.